# What kind of methods do I need to use in order to analyze this kind of health dataset

Tags: descriptive-statistics, biostatistics, multivariate-regression

I've recently been given a dataset with the following variables:

-BMI
-Type of Therapy (indicated by 1, 2, or 3)
-ADH Levels
-HIV positive or negative (0,1 dummy variables)
-Systolic blood pressure
-Diastolic blood pressure
-CD4 Cell Count
-HCV Status (discrete 0 to 4)
-HIV RNA viral load
-Education Level (discrete: 0, 1, 2, 3)
-Age
-Protease Inhibitor Use

I'm being asked to do the following:

1. Describe the distribution of BMI (continuous and using the CDC categories: http://www.cdc.gov/healthyweight/assessing/bmi/adult_bmi/ ) by 5 year age categories, race/ethnicity, education, HIV status, HCV status, viral load, Hypertensive >=140/90 vs. non-hypertensive, current IDU, antiretroviral drug categories
2. Are each of the predictors associated with BMI, our outcome variable?
3. Which predictor(s) were statistically significantly associated with BMI in a full multivariate mode?

Can all this be done in Excel or do I need to use some other statistical software?  I think what would help is if you can specify the method I should be using for each and if there's anything I need to watch out for.  Thanks.

Comment: You *could* do almost anything in Excel given enough time and effort but I probably *wouldn't* do it that way.

Comment: What kind of methods should I use and what kind of software would be the best approach then?

Comment: The questions are rather oddly phrased; it seems that the second item is probably asking for pairwise correlations (to what end I cannot fathom, since we know there are other important variables -- what could the pairwise correlation tell us that's very useful?), and the third presumably seeks multiple regression. You *can* do both in Excel, but I'd use a proper statistics package myself, since they will provide (or makes easy to obtain) particular diagnostics (Excel's limited diagnostics are mostly either misleading or useless). ...ctd

Comment: ctd There are several free ones, such as the ones mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_statistical_software). The most widely used of the free ones is probably R.